# Find all the points that will qualify as being median of X

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Let X have $f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $0<x<1/2$} \\[2ex]
2, & \text{if $3/4<x<1$} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{othewise}
\end{cases}$

Find all the points that will qualify as being median of X: 
I know that $$F_X(x)=\int_0^{1/2}(1)dy+\int_{1/2}^{3/4}(0)dy+\int_{3/4}^{1}(2)dy+\int_{1}^{x}(0)dy$$ was the answer laid out by my lab instructor although this sounds clear I cannot see how to fully draw the CDF from this expression. Since I know that when I draw it I'll just have to select the interval that contains 1/2 as a probability.

I would agree that $F_X(M_X)=1/2$ with $M_X$ being the Median point.
And I would agree that:  $$F_X(x)=\int_0^{x}(1)dy+\int_{1/2}^{x}(0)dy+\int_{3/4}^{x}(2)dy+\int_{1}^{x}(0)dy$$

I would like to get some clarification on that subject.

Sorry for the poorly formed question...

I very much appreciate your input. But I think I may be lacking a very deep understanding of these expressions.

I know that $F_X(x)=P(X\le x)= \int _ 0^xf(t)dt$. I did try to integrate the whole thing and, as expected it gave me 1.

I can understand most of what you're saying but I don't know why you have some x on some of your integrals and not some.

I haven't be shown that way of writing this expression. PLus I drew $f$ and I know f(x)= 0 between 1/2 and 3/4 which means F(x) on that interval gives a constant but since on the pdf(or the question) I don't have a value to integrate I'm lost. I figured doing $\int_{1/2}^{3/4}f(t)dt$

Comment: Why don't you draw the cdf?

Comment: I did. I could just draw the part y=x on [0,1/2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t) dt$. Then just integrating gives
$F(x) = \begin{cases} 0,& x \le 0 \\
x, & x \in [0, {1 \over 2}] \\
{1 \over 2}, & x \in [{1 \over 2}, {3 \over 4}] \\
{1 \over 2} + 2(x-{3 \over 4}), & x \in [ {3 \over 4}, 1] \\
1, & x \ge 1
\end{cases}$

**Aside**: We can write
$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x (1 \cdot 1_{(0,{1 \over 2})}(t) + 2 \cdot 1_{({3 \over 4}, 1)} (t)) dt $.

Look for values $m$ such that $P[ X \ge m] \ge {1 \over 2}$ **and** $P[ X \le m] \ge {1 \over 2} $.

The values of $m$ that satisfy $P[ X \le m] \ge {1 \over 2} $ are $[{1 \over 2}, \infty)$ and the values of $m$ that satisfy $P[ X \ge m] \ge {1 \over 2}$ are
$(-\infty, {3 \over 4}]$.

Comment: $$F_X(x)=\int_0^{x}(1)dy+\int_{1/2}^{x}(0)dy+\int_{3/4}^{x}(2)dy+\int_{1}^{x}(0)dy$$. is that what you used ? If yes, why do you have 1/2 on $x \in  [1/2,3/4]$

Comment: You need to integrate the $f$ given in the questions. Note that $f(x)=0$ for $x \in ({1 \over 2}, {3\over 4})$, so $F(x) = F({1 \over 2})$ for $x$ in this interval.

Comment: (I have no idea where the integral in your comment above comes from.)

Comment: Yes, effectivelly. I'm struggling to know how you get 1/2 on that interval since on the pdf im giving 0 to integrate in there.. which will yield a constant( that I don't know). Do you just assume that since the left part of the CDF has already attained 1/2 you're gonna slide from x=1/2 to 3/4 with the same probability ?

Comment: If $x \in ({1 \over 2}, {3 \over 4})$ then $F(x) = F({1 \over 2}) + \int_{1 \over 2}^x f(t) dt = F({1 \over 2})$.

Comment: Look at the aside I added to the answer for a possibly better way of writing the integral.

Comment: I would suggest drawing the function $f$ and then performing the integration graphically to see why.

Comment: I very much appreciate your input. But I think I may be lacking a very deep understanding of these expressions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83506/discussion-between-mahamad-a-kanoute-and-copper-hat).